# Merge three .gif animations

Tags: merge, gif

I have 3 .gifs animations and I just want to merge them temporally.

Say
g1.gif contains images 1,2,3 sequenced as so
g2.gif contains images 4,5,6 sequenced as so
g3.gif contains images 7,8,9 sequenced as so

I want a gif as follows
g4.gif contains images 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 sequenced as so

I tried `convert *.gif g4.gif` but it overlaps them in a weird fashion. All gifs are the same size, arranging, etc

Thank you so much

Answer (score 7):

the standard `Tool for manipulating GIF images` is [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/)
... here is the syntax to combine several animated gif files

```
gifsicle  g1.gif  g2.gif  g3.gif > combo.gif
```

then to view it just issue

> open combo.gif

Answer (score 2):

```
# install gifsicle
sudo apt install gifsicle

#combine GIF files
gifsicle  *.GIF > combo.gif
```

or

```
gifsicle  *.GIF > combo.gif --colors 256
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use gifsicle, but this command line did not work for me, the resulting file was empty. What worked for me was adding **--merge** to the command:

```
gifsicle --merge My_first_gif.gif example_2.gif hello.gif -o combo.gif --colors 256
```

from: https://davidwalsh.name/merge-gifs